# What datatype is captured with cv2.VideoCapture.read() method in OpenCV?

Tags: python, types, opencv

I am wondering what kind of data type is being captured using the cv2.VideoCapture.read() method. I have been reading the OpenCV documents and I found this explanation:

[image]

I have followed a couple of basic tutorials with OpenCV where a webcam can capture data and outputs the frames. In the picture below the frame data is being shown.

[image]

And here follows the code that outputs these frames:

```
import cv2, time, base64

framesCaptured = 0;
video=cv2.VideoCapture(0) <====== Video capture for the webcam

# Save camera frames as movie
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('recording.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

while True:
    framesCaptured += 1

    check, frame = video.read() <====== Grabs and retrieves frames and decode
    # Write video frames
    out.write(frame)

    # Print out statements
    #print(check)
    print(frame) <====== Print out frame data (as shown in the cmd picture below)

    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow("frame", gray)   

    key=cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == ord('q'):
        break

#print('Frames captured: ' + str(framesCaptured))
video.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

So I am wondering what kind of data type is being printed from the 'frame' variable?

In the end I want to use this 'frame' data to re-construct the images to a video in a C# application.

Comment: In Python, images for OpenCV are stored as numpy arrays. In OpenCV for C++, they are stored as their own custom type, `Mat`.

Comment: It's really fast and easy to develop code in **IPython**, you just type each line of code exactly the same as if you were writing a script in an editor or IDE, but when you want to know what a variable looks like, you just type its name and hit `Enter` and it is nicely formatted for you, or if you want to know its type you just type `type(frame)` and it tells you, then you carry on creating your code. When you have it all looking correct, you just type `%history` and copy the working, debugged code and paste it into a file to save for next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check type of frame yourself by adding `print(type(frame))`.
When I execute script with `print(type(frame))`, `numpy.ndarray` is printed.

Comment: Easy as that. Thank you kindly!